# How to separate single column values into multiple columns by some unique

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

I have a sql query

```
 SELECT e.id,es.userfullname created_by_user,es1.userfullname assigned_to_user 
 FROM lead_activity h 
 JOIN employees es1 on h.assign_to = es1.user_id 
 JOIN leads e ON h.lead_id = e.id 
 JOIN employees es on e.created_by = es.user_id 
 WHERE e.isactive = 1 and DATE_FORMAT(e.date_created,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-12-05' 
 ORDER BY e.created DESC,h.id ASC
```

It's output is given below

```
------------------------
|id | created | assign |
|----------------------|
| 1 | Arijit | Ashish1 |
| 1 | Arijit | Amit2   |
| 1 | Arijit | Vishal3 |
| 1 | Arijit | Vikas4  |
| 2 | Vinod  | Aditya1 |
| 2 | Vinod  | Gourav2 |
| 2 | Vinod  | Alok3   |
------------------------
```

But i want result like below table.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| id | created | assign 1 | assign 2 | assign 3 | assign 4 |  
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Arijit  | Ashish1  | Amit2    | Vishal3  | Vikas4   |
| 2  | Vinod   | Aditya1  | Gourav2  | Alok3    | Null     |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried Group By with `GROUP concatenate (GROUP_CONCAT)` function in select but the problem is that group concatenate change the order of value while comma separating column values and My main goal is to show data Level wise.Therefore i can not use of group concatenate.Suggest something, so that group concatenate function not change order OR changes in above query so that i got above result thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(assign ORDER BY assign SEPARATOR ' ')
```

To make multiple columns follow the 'pivot' tag.